# Couldn't load JSP file in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have been studying Spring MVC recently and got everything worked really well until I tried to use .jsp file as my view page.

> I have swiped through lots of page on how to import .jsp file into
> Spring project but the program still return as a Whitelabel Error
> Page, although I have tried putting my **webapp** folder in any
> direction. *Is there any way to fix my problem? Mine has almost the
> same with anyone else but didn't work correctly like everyone did. I'm
> really appreciate if ya all solve this problem for me. :(*

Here is what I have in my tiny project:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl
            ! This is for using JSP
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper
            ! This is Tomcat, ofc
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.56</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core
            ! Tomcat embed
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.58</version>
        </dependency>


         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.2</version>
        </dependency> -->



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/test_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**CategoryController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "categories")
public class CategoryController {
    
    // http://localhost:8080/categories/
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllCategories(ModelMap modelMap) {

        System.out.println("PLEASE BE WORKING!!!");
        // Add this point when I sent a request to this URL, the program still Sysout the words for me, but the web page didn't show the category.jsp content.

        return "category";
    }

}
```

**category.jsp (This file is in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/category.jsp)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Category List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Category</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a spring boot project not spring mvc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Med. Anyway, I have solved my problem, it was because I opened the project in the wrong way, the settings were correct anyway.